# Do I need to specify x.yf if I define a float?

Tags: c, types, floating-point, double

So my question is whether

```
float a = 1.5 + 1.3;
```

is totally okay, or if one needs to do:

```
float a = 1.5f + 1.3f;
```

I was told that the C compiler takes the float without f as a double, and that that circumstance can lead to unprecise calculations somewhere.

Is that right or is the original way sufficient?

Comment: the original way will (sortof) work however there will be lots of conversions being applied by the compiler.  The conversion from double to float 'can' lose significant digits.  Just as the conversion of the number(s) to double, performing the add, then converting the numbers back to float

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `float a = 1.5 + 1.3;` is equivalent to `float a = (float) (1.5 + 1.3);`, where the addition is a `double` addition between `double` constants.(*)

The end result in `a` is mostly the same as if the addition was a single-precision addition between single-precision constants. In fact, it is better, in the sense that the single-precision version is more likely **not to be** the nearest `float` to 28/10 than the conversion to float of a computation in better precision. Using the best available precision for computations and converting to `float` for storage is one of the reasons for IEEE 754 to have standardized so many precisions (mapped to `float`, `double` and sometimes `long double` in C).

(*) For simplicity, this answer assumes your compiler implements `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`=0. When the compiler implements `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`>0, it automatically stores constants such as `1.3` and computes intermediate results at a better available precision, precisely because this is a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
float a = 1.5 + 1.3;
```

Is OK, but you will normally get a compiler warning such as

```
truncation from 'double' to 'float'
```

which is not a problem sor small numbers.

But it's better to use the f postfix for `float` and no post fix for `douuble`.

Comment: In the case of compile time equations, disagree with "better to use the f postfix for float".  This answer focuses on silencing a truncation warning yet glides over the precision lost doing something like `float a = 0.1f + 6.0f/7.0f` v. `0.1 + 6.0/7.0` which on my platform give slightly different answers.  The `f` one begin less accurate.

Comment: @chux on by platform I get the same result, but you are certainly right. I'm gonna delete this answer.

Comment: IMO your answer concerning compiler warning is useful.